# How to make the custom key while pushing in the Angular 2 firebase database

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app.component.ts is as follows

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

   list: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
    // listing: FirebaseObjectObservable<any[]>;
    constructor(private af:AngularFireDatabase) {
     this.list=this.af.list('/listings');
    //  this.addTask();
   }
   addTask(){
        this.list.push({ 
            name: 'Aswin',
            city:'kochi',
            bedrooms:'rarish@gmail.com',
            image:'9562096886',
            path:'10',
            price:'java',
            title:'3',
            type:'adipoli aanu'
      });
 }

}
```

My view page is like this

```
<input type="submit" (click)="addTask()"/>
```

Now when clicking the submit button it will push the values to angular2 firebase database.But the key name is random like  KmMlBPniR8wpcyBMDOz.

I want to make the key should be custom,ie i want to give my own key name.how it should be possible,please help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In order to create your own key, you shouldn't use the `push()` method.

You can use the `set()` or `update()` method to create a new user at specific database index, for example:

```
this.db.object('users/YOUR_ID').set({
            name: 'Aswin',
            city:'kochi',
            bedrooms:'rarish@gmail.com',
            image:'9562096886',
            path:'10',
            price:'java',
            title:'3',
            type:'adipoli aanu'
      });
```

Comment: addTask(){
        this.list.object('listings/abcd').set()({ 
            name: 'Aswin',
            city:'kochi',
            bedrooms:'rarish@gmail.com',
            image:'9562096886',
            path:'10',
            price:'java',
            title:'3',
            type:'adipoli aanu'
      });
 }

Comment: addTask(){
        this.list.object('listings/abcd').set()({ 
            name: 'Aswin',
            city:'kochi',
            bedrooms:'rarish@gmail.com',
            image:'9562096886',
            path:'10',
            price:'java',
            title:'3',
            type:'adipoli aanu'
      });
 }

Comment: i updated the code like above but it doesnt work for me