# How to create custom key Angular Firebase CRUD to make a Nested Child

Tags: angular, web

I've recently started learning Angular and would like help in figuring out how to make a nested child of a specific order.

[This is how I want the table to look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yTCY.jpg)

[However this is how the result that I have come up with so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiDau.png)

Code from "product.ts"

```
export interface Product {
  $key: string;
  CategoryID: string;
  Description: string;
  Image: string;
  Name: string;
  Price: string;
  imageList: Array<string>;
}
```

Code from "product.service.ts"

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from './product';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList, AngularFireObject } from '@angular/fire/database';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ProductService {
  productsRef: AngularFireList<any>;
  productRef: AngularFireObject<any>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  /* Create Product */
  AddProduct(product: Product) {
    this.productsRef.push ({
      CategoryID: product.CategoryID,
      Description: product.Description,
      Image: product.Image,
      Name: product.Name,
      Price: product.Price,
      ImageList: product.imageList
    })
    .catch(error => {
      this.errorMgmt(error);
    });
  }

  /* Get Product */
  GetProduct(id: string) {
    this.productRef = this.db.object('products-list/' + id);
    return this.productRef;
  }

  /* Get Product List */
  GetProductList() {
    this.productsRef = this.db.list('products-list');
    return this.productRef;
  }

  /* Update Product */
  UpdateProduct(id, product: Product) {
    this.productRef.update({
      CategoryID: product.CategoryID,
      Description: product.Description,
      Image: product.Image,
      Name: product.Name,
      Price: product.Price,
      ImageList: product.imageList
    })
    .catch(error => {
      this.errorMgmt(error);
    });
  }

  /* Delete Product */
  DeleteProduct(id: string) {
    this.productRef = this.db.object('products-list/' + id);
    this.productRef.remove()
    .catch(error => {
      this.errorMgmt(error);
    });
  }

  /* Error Management */
  private errorMgmt(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
} /* End of Export */
```

Code from add-product.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { COMMA, ENTER } from '@angular/cdk/keycodes';
import { MatChipInputEvent } from '@angular/material';
import { ProductService } from './../../shared/product.service';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { splitClasses } from '@angular/compiler';

export interface ImageList {
  name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-product',
  templateUrl: './add-product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-product.component.css']
})

export class AddProductComponent implements OnInit {
  visible = true;
  selectable = true;
  removable = true;
  addOnBlur = true;
  imageArray: ImageList[] = [];
  @ViewChild('chipList', {static: false}) chipList;
  @ViewChild('resetProductForm', {static: false}) myNgForm;
  readonly separatorKeysCodes: number[] = [ENTER, COMMA];
  selectedCategoryType: string;
  productForm: FormGroup;
  CategoryType: any = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10'];

  constructor(
    public fb: FormBuilder,
    private productApi: ProductService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.productApi.GetProductList();
    this.submitProductForm();
  }

  /* Remove Duplciated Image Links */
  remove(prodimgList: ImageList): void {
    const index = this.imageArray.indexOf(prodimgList);
    if (index >= 0) {
      this.imageArray.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  /* Reactive Product Form */
  submitProductForm() {
    this.productForm = this.fb.group({
      prod_CategoryID: ['', [Validators.required]],
      prod_Description: ['', [Validators.required]],
      prod_Image: ['', [Validators.required]],
      prod_Name: ['', [Validators.required]],
      prod_Price: ['', [Validators.required]],
      prod_ImageList: [this.imageArray]
    });
  }

  /* Error Handling */
  public handleError = (controlName: string, errorName: string) => {
    return this.productForm.controls[controlName].hasError(errorName);
  }

  /* Reset Form */
  resetForm() {
    this.imageArray = [];
    this.productForm.reset();
    Object.keys(this.productForm.controls).forEach(key => {
      this.productForm.controls[key].setErrors(null);
    });
  }

  /* Submit Form */
  submitProduct() {
    if (this.productForm.valid) {
      this.productApi.AddProduct(this.productForm.value);
      this.resetForm();
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve above thing using **set** method to create customNameIndex(as '01' etc. )

**Note:** I gave public permission to my cloud firebase(in RealTimeDatabase). To acheive same JSON type as u mentioned in 2nd screenshot then your imagesList should be an object not an array. If you do not have public permission you need to be authenticated in order to insert rows in realtimedatabase.

I configured my firebase & angular by following this link. [firebase techdiaries](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-firestore-tutorial/).  (I saved all configurations in environment.ts file). I followed this link for creating customKey to google firebase. [creating customKey in firebase medium](https://medium.com/@nsrathore/creating-custom-key-for-new-record-in-realtime-database-firebase-angular-48659118d047)

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';

 dbRef:any;
 constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore,private fireDB: AngularFireDatabase) {

  }
  createData() {
      // for creating customKey 
      this.dbRef = this.fireDB.database.ref('images'); // i have collection named images in google firebase 
      this.dbRef.child('02').set({
        categoryId:"bond",
        Description:"bond",
        imageList:{
          "image1":"asdfasdf",
          "image2":"asdfasdfasdf"
        }
      });
   }
```

Following link might help.

[create custom key SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44485654/how-to-make-the-custom-key-while-pushing-in-the-angular-2-firebase-database)